# Copying LinearLayout views

Tags: java, android, layout, mobile

I'm trying to copy and then edit a layout view defined in an XML file.

```java
//Create layout  
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);


//Add views
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
//layout.addView(textView);

setContentView(layout);
```

This seems like it should work, but every time I run it, the app crashes when I call line 
`setContentView(layout);`.
I've double checked the id's and they are fine and they are both `LinearLayouts`.
 Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: please post your logcat error stack trace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply you can't call `findViewById` before `setContentView` because there is no layout set to find a view in! What will happen probably is `findViewById` will return `null`, and then you attempt to set the content as `layout` (which is null) thus getting an error there.

Call `setContentView` with your layout resource ID or actual view first, then find your `LinearLayout` with `findViewById`.

Comment: Thanks so much i completely missed that.